# How can I add TextChange Listener to all EditText?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have several `EditText` and I want to disappear the error from the `TextInputLayout`, once the user changes the text, how can I do it so it can detect the text changing from all the `Textview`s? I think, is implementing some class but I don't know which, and that's assuming that's the solution, I'm new to kotlin, sorry if the question seems dumb

```
  class AuxiliaryChangesInfoActivity: AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_auxiliary_changes_info)

        hideErrorMessage()
        img_close_auxiliary_changes.setOnClickListener({

            onBackPressed()
        })

        txt_save_auxiliary_changes.setOnClickListener({

            if(txt_description_auxiliary_charges_info.text.isEmpty()){
                tI_description_auxiliary_charges_info.error="You need to specify a Description"


            }
            else if(txt_frequency_auxiliary_charges_info.text.isEmpty()){
                tI_frequency_auxiliary_charges_info.error="You need to specify a frequency"
            }
            else if(txt_to_auxiliary_charges_info.text.isEmpty()){
                tI_to_auxiliary_charges_info.error="You need to specify a to value"
            }
            else if(txt_from_auxiliary_charges_info.text.isEmpty()){
                tI_from_auxiliary_charges_info.error="You need to specify a from value"
            }
            else if(txt_qty_auxiliary_charges_info.text.isEmpty()){
                tI_qty_auxiliary_charges_info.error="You need to specify a quantity value"
            }
        })



    }

    @OnTextChanged(R.id.txt_description_auxiliary_charges_info,
            R.id.txt_frequency_auxiliary_charges_info,
            R.id.txt_from_auxiliary_charges_info,
            R.id.txt_to_auxiliary_charges_info,
            R.id.txt_qty_auxiliary_charges_info,
            callback = OnTextChanged.Callback.AFTER_TEXT_CHANGED)
     fun hideErrorMessage() {
        // your code here
        tI_description_auxiliary_charges_info.isErrorEnabled = false
        tI_frequency_auxiliary_charges_info.isErrorEnabled = false
        tI_from_auxiliary_charges_info.isErrorEnabled = false
        tI_to_auxiliary_charges_info.isErrorEnabled=false
        tI_qty_auxiliary_charges_info.isErrorEnabled=false
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `CustomEditText` class

```
class CustomEditText : EditText {

    private var mContext: Context? = null
    private var attributeSet: AttributeSet? = null

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        this.mContext = context
        initCustomEditText()
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
        this.mContext = context
        this.attributeSet = attrs
        initCustomEditText()
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
        this.mContext = context
        this.attributeSet = attrs
        initCustomEditText()
    }

    private fun initCustomEditText() {

        this.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            }
            override fun afterTextChanged(arg0: Editable) {
                if(context is MainActivity){
                    (context as MainActivity).tI_description_auxiliary_charges_info.isErrorEnabled=false
                }else if(context is MainActivity2){
                    (context as MainActivity2).tI_description_auxiliary_charges_info.isErrorEnabled=false
                }
                // ... other Activity
            }
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
        })

    }

}
```

Make sure -

1. Your `MainActivity` (don't know yours since you haven't mentioned) and `tI_description_auxiliary_charges_info` both are `public`
2. All your `EditText` in XML change to like `com.a4plus1.com.dhq_app.Components.CustomEditText` (package name.CustomEditText)

Comment: but, if I want to implement that in several classes I would have to make a custom class for each, "MainActivity"?

Comment: using `is` you still can be using one custom `EditText` class for each `Activity` :) Check my update

Comment: I implemented your past answer, and I had no luck, it doesn't detect the text changing

Comment: That's strange, check out my [github project](https://github.com/Paulkit/Test_Kotlin_stackoverflow), `CustomEditText` is work on detecting text changes, and distinguish different activities

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want to share a single TextWatcher among multiple TextInputLayouts. There may be several possible solutions; one approach would be:

1. add [Android's KTX](https://github.com/android/android-ktx) to module dependencies
2. define a [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#afterTextChanged(android.text.Editable)) with your validation logic
3. traverse the views, adding your textWatcher to each [TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html#setError(java.lang.CharSequence))

   ```
   // app module's build.gradle
   dependencies {
       // #1
       implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:0.3'
   }

   // sample Activity.kt
   private lateinit var layout: ConstraintLayout

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       layout = findViewById(R.id.coordinator)
       addTextWatcherToEditTexts()
   }

   // #2
   private val textWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
       override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
           layout.children.forEach { view ->
               (view as? TextInputLayout)?.let {
                   with(it) {
                       error = null
                       isErrorEnabled = false
                   }
               }
           }
       }

       override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
           // no-op
       }

       override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
           // no-op
       }
   }

   // #3
   private fun addTextWatcherToEditTexts() {
       layout.children.forEach { view ->
           (view as? EditText)?.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind adding a new dependency, you should consider using [Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/).
It is compatible with kotlin, and with it you can write things like this :

```
@OnTextChanged(R.id.txt_description_auxiliary_charges_info,
        R.id.txt_frequency_auxiliary_charges_info,
        R.id.third_edit_text,
        ...,
        callback = OnTextChanged.Callback.AFTER_TEXT_CHANGED)
fun hideErrorMessage(editable: Editable) {
    // your code here
    // tI_description_auxiliary_charges_info.isErrorEnabled = false
}
```

To add it to your project, add this to your project build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    ...
    classpath "com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:$butterknife_version"
}
```

and this to your app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

dependencies {
    ...    
    compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$butterknife_version"
    kapt "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$butterknife_version"
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm just responding to your solution, I just had time to test this, and it's no working I don't know why, it shows the error but noI just updated my code, if you could point me what I'm doing wrong thank you very much